# Where do I find all the ipset options?

Tags: linux, ipset, ubuntu-22.04

Where do I find all the ipset options (ipset v7.15)?.

[man ipset online](https://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html) are not all. I didn't find them on the command line either, by running:

```
man ipset
ipset --help
```

For example this options:

```
ipset -A
ipset -F
ipset -N
# maybe more options
```

In tests carried out, the output of these commands is the same:

```
ipset -A = ipset add
ipset -F = ipset flush
ipset -N = ipset create
```

But I would like to access an official documentation that clarifies it

Comment: Best documentation ever: http://git.netfilter.org/ipset/tree/src/ui.c?h=v7.15

Comment: as far as I know, those options you have found are included only for compatibility to older versions of ipset scripts - since they are superfluous (and deprecated!), they are not documented any more. So, the man page of ipset you have already found is the best documentation available out there...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for the documentation provided. The question has been solved

Comment: If the question is solved, either write your own answer to it (and accepted it after the delay), or remove it. Because it will still "ping" randomly in the questions needing an answer.

Comment: @A.B I can't answer and accept it myself, because it wasn't me who provided the solution, but jabbson and Martin. I can't delete the question either, because it would be disrespectful to these people who solved the question. What can happen is that the users who helped publish the answer to select it as correct